# AWS Developer Authenticated Identities using Android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I am trying to use a Developer Authenticated Provider to login to my android app basing it loosely off of this demo:  https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/master/CognitoSyncDemo.  I successfully logged in through our own backend got the idToken and subsequently got session credentials to access our AWS database.  I then used those credentials to make a POST to the db.

But this only worked once, now I cannot get through again, without having changed any code.  I am also using a generated SDK through http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-generate-sdk.html.  I'm not sure if this is causing any errors.

Here is my DeveloperAuthenticationProvider:

```
public class AuthenticationProvider extends
    AWSAbstractCognitoDeveloperIdentityProvider {

private static final String TAG = AuthenticationProvider.class.getSimpleName();

private static SocializeClient mSocializeClient;

private static final String developerProvider = Constants.AWS_PROVIDER_NAME;
private static final String cognitoSampleDeveloperAuthenticationAppEndpoint = UrlEndpoints.URL_DOMAIN;

public AuthenticationProvider(Context context, String accountId, String identityPoolId, Regions region) {
    super(accountId, identityPoolId, region);

    /*
     * Initialize the client using which you will communicate with your
     * backend for user authentication.
     */
    AWSCredentialsProvider awsCredentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
            context,
            this,
            region
    );

    ApiClientFactory factory = new ApiClientFactory()
            .endpoint(cognitoSampleDeveloperAuthenticationAppEndpoint)
            .credentialsProvider(awsCredentialsProvider);

    mSocializeClient = factory.build(SocializeClient.class);

}

/*Only refreshes the login info, when it has expired*/

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCognitoIdentityProvider#refresh() In refresh
 * method, you will have two flows:
 */
/*
 * 1. When the app user uses developer authentication. In this case, make
 * the call to your developer backend, from where call the
 * GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity API of Amazon Cognito service. Be sure to call update(), so as to
 * set the identity id and the token received.
 */
/*
 * 2.When the app user is not using the developer authentication, just call
 * the refresh method of the AWSAbstractCognitoDeveloperIdentityProvider
 * class which actually calls GetId and GetOpenIDToken API of Amazon
 * Cognito.
 */
@Override
public String refresh() {
    Log.i(TAG, "refresh");
    // If there is a key with developer provider name in the logins map, it
    // means the app user has used developer credentials
    if (!loginsMap.isEmpty()
            && loginsMap.containsKey(developerProvider)) {
        Log.i(TAG, "contains provider");
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "does not contain developer provider");
        Map<String, String> logins = new HashMap<>();
        logins.put(developerProvider, UserSingleton.imei);
        setLogins(logins);
    }

    // TODO:: Temp code to login. Once available, need to add code to GetToken from SocializeClient
    Login login = new Login();
    login.setImei(UserSingleton.imei);
    login.setPassword(UserSingleton.password);
    LoginReponse loginReponse = mSocializeClient.socializeAuthLoginPost(login);
    Log.i(TAG, "login response: " + loginReponse.getIdentityId() + " - token: " + loginReponse.getToken());

    update(loginReponse.getIdentityId(), loginReponse.getToken());

    Log.i(TAG, "updated");

    return loginReponse.getToken();
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see com.amazonaws.auth.AWSBasicCognitoIdentityProvider#getIdentityId()
 */
/*
 * This method again has two flows as mentioned above depending on whether
 * the app user is using developer authentication or not. When using
 * developer authentication system, the identityId should be retrieved from
 * the developer backend. In the other case the identityId will be retrieved
 * using the getIdentityId() method which in turn calls Cognito GetId and
 * GetOpenIdToken APIs.
 */
@Override
public String getIdentityId() {
    Log.i(TAG, "getIdentityId");
    identityId = CognitoSyncClientManager.credentialsProvider.getCachedIdentityId();
    if (identityId == null) {
        Log.i(TAG, "identityId is null");
        if (!loginsMap.isEmpty()
                && loginsMap.containsKey(developerProvider)) {
            Log.i(TAG, "grabbing identityId using logins map");

            // TODO:: Temp code to login. Once available, need to add code to GetToken from SocializeClient
            Login login = new Login();
            login.setImei(loginsMap.get(developerProvider));
            login.setPassword(UserSingleton.password);
            LoginReponse loginReponse = mSocializeClient.socializeAuthLoginPost(login);
            Log.i(TAG, "login response: " + loginReponse.getIdentityId() + " - token: " + loginReponse.getToken());

            update(loginReponse.getIdentityId(), loginReponse.getToken());

            return loginReponse.getIdentityId();
        } else {
            return super.getIdentityId();
        }
    } else {
        return identityId;
    }
}

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see
 * com.amazonaws.auth.AWSAbstractCognitoIdentityProvider#getProviderName()
 * Return the developer provider name which you chose while setting up the
 * identity pool in the Amazon Cognito Console
 */
@Override
public String getProviderName() {
    return developerProvider;
}

/**
 * This function validates the user credentials against the sample Cognito
 * developer authentication application. After that it stores the key and
 * token received from sample Cognito developer authentication application
 * for all further communication with the application.
 *
 * @param imei
 * @param password
 */
public void login(String imei, String password, Context context) {
    Log.i(TAG, "login");
    Login login = new Login();
    login.setImei(imei);
    login.setPassword(password);
    new AuthenticationTask(context).execute(login);
}

public void publishProfile(Context context, Profile profile){

    Log.i(TAG, "publishProfile");
    ProfileKey profileKey = new ProfileKey();
    profileKey.setUserID(identityId);
    profile.setKey(profileKey);

    new UploadProfileTask(context).execute(profile);
}

protected static SocializeClient getSocializeClientInstance() {
    if (mSocializeClient == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                "Dev Auth Client not initialized yet");
    }
    return mSocializeClient;
}
```

}

Here is my AuthenticationTask as well where I attempt to login, then grab credentials to access the AWS database:

```
public class AuthenticationTask extends
    AsyncTask<Login, Void, Void> {

private static final String TAG = AuthenticationTask.class.getSimpleName();

// The user name or the developer user identifier you will pass to the
// Amazon Cognito in the GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity API
private String mImei;
private String mPassword;

private GetCredentialsForIdentityResult credentialsForIdentityResult;

private boolean isSuccessful;

private final Context context;

public AuthenticationTask(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Login... params) {
    Log.i(TAG, "doInBackground get refreshing threshold: " + CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider.DEFAULT_THRESHOLD_SECONDS);

    mImei = params[0].getImei();
    mPassword = params[0].getPassword();

    Login login = params[0];

    //        if(mPassword == null){
    //        Log.i(TAG, "register");
    //        mPassword = Utils.generateRandomString();
    //        final Register register = new Register();
    //        register.setImei(mImei);
    //        register.setPassword(mPassword);
    //        login.setPassword(mPassword);

    //        RegisterResponse registerResponse = AuthenticationProvider.getSocializeClientInstance().socializeAuthRegisterPost(register);
    //        Log.i(TAG, "registerResponse: " + registerResponse.getCreated());

    UserSingleton.password = mPassword;
    UserSingleton.getInstance().saveRegistrationInfo();
    Log.i(TAG, "imei: " + mImei);
    //        }

    Log.i(TAG, "calling login post");
    LoginReponse loginReponse = AuthenticationProvider.getSocializeClientInstance().socializeAuthLoginPost(login);
    Log.i(TAG, "login response: " + loginReponse.getIdentityId() + " - token: " + loginReponse.getToken());

    // Set up the loginsMap to send with the credentials request
    Map<String, String> loginsMap = new HashMap<>();
    loginsMap.put(CognitoSyncClientManager.developerIdentityProvider.getProviderName(), loginReponse.getToken());

    // get AWS credentials to access DB
    GetCredentialsForIdentityRequest credentialsForIdentityRequest = new GetCredentialsForIdentityRequest();
    credentialsForIdentityRequest.setIdentityId(loginReponse.getIdentityId());
    credentialsForIdentityRequest.setLogins(loginsMap);

    Log.i(TAG, "credentials request: " + credentialsForIdentityRequest.getIdentityId() + credentialsForIdentityRequest.getLogins());

    AmazonCognitoIdentityClient cognitoIdentityClient = new AmazonCognitoIdentityClient(CognitoSyncClientManager.credentialsProvider);
    credentialsForIdentityResult = cognitoIdentityClient
            .getCredentialsForIdentity(credentialsForIdentityRequest);

    isSuccessful = credentialsForIdentityResult != null;
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    if (isSuccessful) {
        Log.i(TAG, "accessKeyId: " + credentialsForIdentityResult.getCredentials().getAccessKeyId()
                + "\nsecretKey: " + credentialsForIdentityResult.getCredentials().getSecretKey()
                + "\nsessionToken: " + credentialsForIdentityResult.getCredentials().getSessionToken());

        CognitoSyncClientManager
                .addLogins(
                        ((AuthenticationProvider) CognitoSyncClientManager.credentialsProvider
                                .getIdentityProvider()).getProviderName(),
                        mImei);
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "login error: " + result);
    }
}
```

}

In my refresh call I am just relogging in. I'm not sure if that is correct.

The biggest issue now is upon startup when I attempt to login using, `mSocializeClient.socializeAuthLoginPost(login)` it seems to call refresh every time, before it even logs in.  Refresh then attempts to login again and it keeps calling itself endlessly.

Any help/explanations would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The way the dev auth sample works is as follows:

1. The [DeveloperAuthenticationTask.login()](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/blob/master/CognitoSyncDemo/src/com/amazonaws/cognito/sync/demo/DeveloperAuthenticationTask.java) is supposed to login to the server and get a session key.
2. It sets up the logins map and calls [DeveloperAuthenticationProvider.refresh()](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/blob/master/CognitoSyncDemo/src/com/amazonaws/cognito/sync/demo/DeveloperAuthenticationProvider.java)
3. Refresh exchanges the session key with the server for a valid cognito token and identity id and calls update with the token and identity id.

In your case, you don't have this session key, just username and password.  So you don't need the AuthenticationTask.  All you need is:

1. a login() in your AuthenticationProvider, that puts the username/password in a secure location, sets up the login map and calls refresh (it shouldn't actually attempt to login to your service).
2. In refresh() you retrieve the username/pass from the secure location, call your service and then call update with the token and identity id returned from your service.

Can you simplify your code to this flow?